# Is it possible to create an event to automatically register what I print in the Laravel console to a specific log?

Tags: laravel, logging, command

It is possible to create an automatic event that when I execute a custom command I print in a log file all the ECHOs that have the code without having to place 2 lines, for example:

```
echo "Send email";
Log::channel('mail')->info("Send email");
```

Because right now I'm running the lines so that I record in the log each echo I'm printing but I think it could improve that or optimize but do not know how or is that if it could.

Comment: what you could do is create a helper `helper_echo` and replace your regular echo with this and handle `LOG:` there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this variant to loggin all users activities. For what you write echo? I dont understand. See my example, maybe I can help you. Automatic event you can do with middlewares.

UserActivityLoggerMiddleware.php

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $log = new Logger('name');
        if(!Auth::check())
        {
            $log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('../storage/logs/Guest.log', Logger::INFO));
        } else
            $log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('../storage/logs/'.Auth::user()->login.'.log', Logger::INFO));

        $log->info("------------------");
        $log->info("Пользователь перешел по маршруту - ".$request->url()." Параметры ". $request->method());

           foreach($request->all() as $key => $item)
           {
               $log->info($key." => ".$item);
           }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: It is a process of sending emails by console that runs at midnight and would like to have a record of which emails are sent. 

It is not something that is enabled for all users but only the platform. For example I have emails that run every 7, 14 days and 2 months and would like to keep a log of whether or not I send.